# WebService Client in Java

Tags: java, web

I have the following problem: I am completely new to java EE (know only about servlets and JSPs) and especially web services. 
I need to develop a client for a web service (it needs to query the service for useful information once in a minute). 
In my mind this client would be a simple java-SWing-based program, which would query the web service through simple Socket when the application client runs. How can that be done?
Is it possible to do in that way? If not, which is the easiest way to create such a client?

Comment: You need to know about the web service you will be calling.  What type of web service is it (SOAP/REST)?  If you are developing the client to call the web service you don't have to worry about Java EE.  Swing has nothing to do with the web service call - just how you want to display an interface to the user.  Sockets may or may not be a factor depending on the web service you are calling.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/). Simple and powerful framework. 
And yes, that is possible to implement what you said using this framework. Just read tutorials and play around for a bit with it.

Answer (score 1):

Inorder to connect to a web service using a java client follow the below mentioned steps:
1. Get the URL in which the webservice is hosted. This is usually of the fomat `http://<IP_OF_SERVER>:<PORT_OF_SERVER>/<WEB_APP_NAME>?wsdl`
2. Get the [qualified name](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/namespace/QName.html) of the service:

```
        //   1st arg is the service URI
        //   2nd is the service name published in the WSDL
QName qname = new QName(<Service_URI>, <SERVICE_NAME_PUBLISHED_WSDL>);<br/>
```

3. Create a factory for the [service](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Service.html):

```
            Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
```

4. Extract the endpoint interface, the service "port":

```
<Port_Class_Name> eif = service.getPort(<Port_Class_Name>);
```

5. Now use the methods on the Port, which are the actual methods in your webservice.

Comment: Which libraries whould be included for that? And is it ok if create a socket which connects to URL specified in step 1?

Comment: There is no need to include any specific library for this, these are JDK libraries itself.<br/> You need to connect to the URL specified in step 1 exclusively. Step 3 takes care of connecting to the URL.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try REST Webservice, try [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/)  REST (or others). With rest you can connect it with http connection (GET and POST).

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to connect to a web service using a java client follow the below mentioned steps:

1.URL wsdlUrl = new URL("your wsdl url);

2.QName qname = new QName("targetNamespace in ur wsdl file","service name in your wsdl file");

3. Service service = Services.create(wsdlUrl,qname);

4.suppose getData() is your SEI
   GetData data = (GetData)service.getPort(GetData.class);

5.call the your methods using data object
ex:data.getId(String name); this will return your response